# Python Zeep: How to determine whether message has an attachment?

Tags: python, zeep

I have to query a third party SOAP endpoint. This endpoint sometimes have an attachment, and sometimes it only has plain XML. I don't have a way of knowing what it going to be before I get the response and inspect it.

The previous developer did something like this:

```py
result = client.service.download(
    # parameters
)

# TODO remove unresolved reference when I understand zeep library better
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
message_type = zeep.wsdl.attachments.MessagePack
if isinstance(result, message_type):
    content = str(result.attachments[0].content, encoding='utf-8')
else:
    content = serialize_object(result)["fileContents"]
```

I would like to have a way to determine the type of response I got without having to suppress "Unresolved Reference" complaints from my IDE. It would also be nice to avoid using exceptions for flow control, i.e. handling an `AttributeError` when calling `result.root`.

Does Zeep have some canonical way to determine whether the response has an attachment? I'm struggling to find something like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if I try to serialize the result, I can check whether or not I got a dictionary.

```py
result = client.service.download(
    # parameters
)
_result = serialize_object(result)

if not isinstance(_result, dict):
    _result = serialize_object(result.root)
    _result["fileContents"] = str(result.attachments[0].content, encoding='utf-8')

# use _result going forward
```